# "this" in a nested JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function, scope, this

```
function TheTable(calculateButtonId)
{
    this.errorsBlock = document.getElementById("Some Value");

    var addError = function(text) {
        this.errorsBlock.innerText += text + "\n";
    }

    var customHandler = function(desc, page, line, chr) {
        addError("[" + line + "] " + desc);
        return true;
    }
    this.init = function() {
        window.onerror = customHandler;
        ......................
    }
    this.init();
}

var table = new TheTable("BtnId");
```

as soon as I changed `this.addError` to `var addError` it started to thow an error:

```
Cannot set property 'innerText' of undefined
```

Could you clarify, what am I referencing by `this` inside of var-function?

Comment: Where are you calling `addError`?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, because `addError` is now local to `TheTable` but you never call it there. You are leaving something out.

Comment: Read [the introduction to `this` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). For "*what am I referencing by this?*" - it's `undefined` as your error message says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things:

- Whenever you invoke a function using the `new` keyword -- e.g. `new TheTable("BtnId")` -- you create a new instance of that type. The value of `this` inside that constructor refers to this new instance.
- You can add arbitrary properties to this new instance.
- In general, when you invoke a function that has been assigned to this new object, then the value of `this` inside the function is that same instance.
- The `var` keyword creates a variable scoped to its nearest enclosing function. In general, when you invoke functions of this type (i.e. functions created as global or local variables), the value of `this` inside them is `window`.

So when you do this:

```
this.errorsBlock = document.getElementById("Some Value");

this.addError = function(text) {
    this.errorsBlock.innerText += text + "\n";
}

this.addError("whatever");
```

...then the value of `this` inside `addError` refers to the same object that `errorsBlock` was assigned to and the call succeeds. However, when you change it to this:

```
var addError = function(text) {
    this.errorsBlock.innerText += text + "\n";
}

addError("whatever");
```

...then the value of `this` inside `addError` is `window` and `window` probably doesn't have any function property named `errorsBlock` and the call fails.

Comment: Plus the comment from Bergi (nice link - there is written that in strict mode `this` will be `undefined` - what a surprise!)

Answer (score 1):

```
function TheTable(calculateButtonId) {
    this.errorsBlock = document.getElementById("Some Value");
    var self = this;
    var addError = function(text) {
        self.errorsBlock.innerText += text + "\n";
    }
}
```

this in javascript is always context under which function is running.

Comment: I would avoid using `self`, since `self` is a predefined variable (it refers to `window`). This can lead to really confusing bugs (since `self` is never `undefined`).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: It's totally fine when used in a local scope with `var`.

Comment: @Bergi  Yeah, ddin't say it doesn't work. But once someone, somewhere makes a mistake (like, forgets to declare self in the current scope, or assumes a higher scope already declared id) it can (& probably will) cause extra confusion :-)